# Automatically save user scope settings ON CHANGE in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, settings

I often find myself doing this for user scope settings:

`My.Settings.MySetting = MyValue
My.Settings.Save()`

Granted, user scope settings in VB.NET are saved automatically on exit, but still, it's safer to save on change in case of unexpected termination or session crashes occur.

My question: Is there a way that I'm not aware of to let changes in settings automatically trigger the saving mechanism?

Comment: It is the exact opposite.  It is much, *much* safer to save settings at program exit.  The way you want to do it might create a very ugly scenario when the changed setting causes the program to crash.  Restarting it will make it crash again.  Over and over again.  The user is completely and utterly stuck, reinstalling the program won't fix the problem and he'll never find the bad file.  If your program routinely crashes, thus inspiring this hack, do work on *that* problem instead.

Comment: The object exposed via `My.Settings` has a `PropertyChanged` event that you could handle and call `Save` there.

Comment: @HansPassant
I wouldn't call the "save on change" model a "hack". Think of it more like an "auto save" feature. And no, not even remotely close to "routine crashes". Actually, none that I can recall during my tests thus far. Anyway, I ended up going the "save on exit" route, mainly because it plays more nicely with the "Cancel" functionality, in which case it wouldn't make sense for the settings to have been saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jmcilhinney said:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents MySettings As My.MySettings = My.Settings

    Private Sub MySettings_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles MySettings.PropertyChanged
        MySettings.Save()
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you want to know which setting was changed, use `e.PropertyName`

Comment: I went with the "save on exit" model, but your answer works so accepted.